# What is the chronological order of Higurashi no Naku Koro ni?

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

I want to know what is (if there is any) the chronological order for this variety series if I'm going to watch it from the start:

- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kai
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kaku: Outbreak
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Rei

If there is more that I didn't mention, please add it also if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Relationdiagram]
<sub>Diagram from [AniSearch](http://en.anisearch.com/anime/1931,higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni/relations). Click to enlarge!</sub>

If I am not wrong now and I interpreted the diagram the right way the viewing order of the anime series should be like this. The bold text is the main story!

**Higurashi no Naku Koro ni (05.04.2006)**

*Shared Universe*

- Umineko no Naku Koro ni (02.06.2009)
- Umineko no Naku Koro ni: Uraneko (23.10.2009)
- Ookamikakushi (08.01.2010)

*Side Story*

- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kira (21.06.2011)

*Side Story*

- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kaku: Outbreak (15.08.2013)

**Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kai (06.06.2007)**

*Side Story*

- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Gaiden: Nekogoroshi-hen (02.08.2007)

*Other*

- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kai: Ura Higu (21.09.2007)

**Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Rei (25.02.2009)**