# Order to read Higurashi no Naku Koro Ni

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

I want to know the order in which the Higurashi series need to be read in, the series being the following:

- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Watanagashi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Tsumihoroboshihen
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Minagoroshi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Onikakushi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Yoigoshi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Matsuribayashi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni  Utsutsukowashi
- Higurashi No Naku Koro Ni Kai Meakashi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni  Onisarashi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni  Tatarigoroshi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni ~ Himatsubushi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni ~ Hirukowashi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni - Tatarigoroshihen
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kai - Minagoroshihen
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni ~ Hinageshi
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Jan
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni - Kataribanashihen
- Higurashi no Naku Koro ni - Kokoro Iyashi Hen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the chronological order of Higurashi no Naku Koro ni?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14583/what-is-the-chronological-order-of-higurashi-no-naku-koro-ni), altough it might be outdated.

Comment: @DJPirtu Not sure if it is an exact duplicate of that question, which asks for the viewing order of the anime, whereas this question asks for the reading order of the manga.

Comment: This is for either the manga or the visual novels, so I don't think it's a duplicate. It might be nice if we could have the answers for all media on one question, but since it didn't work out that way, I don't think we should close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when it comes to manga that's the recommended order:

1. Onikakushi-hen
2. Watanagashi-hen
3. Tatarigoroshi-hen
4. Himatsubushi-hen
5. Meakashi-hen
6. Tsumihoroboshi-hen
7. Minagoroshi-hen
8. Matsuribayashi-hen

Optional (Extra Stories):

5. Utsutsukowashi-hen
6. Yoigoshi-hen
7. Saikoroshi-hen
8. Onisarashi-hen
9. Batsukoishi-hen
10. Hirukowashi-hen

All of these are different iterations of the same period of time, but they focus on different aspects.

Though personally, I still recommend reading the Visual Novels: Higurashi no Naku Koro ni & Higurashi no Naku Koro ni Kai.